# I have a force in eV/Angstroms. How do I convert it so that the speed I calculate is in Angstroms/second?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, soft-question

How can I express speed in Angstroms/second after application of a force that's in eV/Angstrom (given the mass, original velocity and time elapsed)?

Comment: This is impossible, because the force and mass only determines the acceleration (via F=ma), but not the speed. Besides, "velocity" is the correct word here; "speed" may be an acceptable word but it is at least not professional

Comment: @wzkchem5 and speed/velocity is a * t, right? So if I also know the time it should be possible? I am just very confused in those small measurements.

Comment: No. The change of velocity within an infinitesimal time dt is a*dt. The relation does not hold if the time interval is not infinitesimal. So you have to know (1) the original velocity, and (2) the time period; moreover, the time period has to be extremely short. With those in hand, you can calculate the velocity right after that extremely short time period.

Comment: @wzkchem5 yes I have all this data. Sorry for not formulating the question correctly. I edited it. Can you give an answer based on that?

Comment: @JohnT As a matter of courtesy, I have answered your question, but I would like to know what level of formal physics education you have? Have you completed any high-school/A-level physics courses? Have you taken any physics courses at the university or community college level? You have a history of asking us what we call "[tag:soft-question]s" and without answers to my above questions to you, it's very difficult for us to decide how to deal with your questions in the future.

Comment: I think this question better belongs to the Physics stackexchange.

Comment: @Sha [The poster gets to choose which site to post their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/391772). On MMSE, we only migrate questions to other SE sites if the question is struggling to find an answer here (or is likely to struggle to get an answer here). Likewise, you could say that **many** questions on Physics.SE "belong" here at MMSE (just see for example, the questions in their DFT tag, and the fact that 30% of all MMSE questions have the DFT tag, so it's "our territory"), but that's just how this complex network of Q/A sites works :)

Comment: @NikeDattani thanks for your clarification.

Comment: This is basically a homework question. Do we answer those here?

Comment: I second @B.Kelly.  Is there an MMSE policy for homework questions?

Comment: @B.Kelly , EverydayFoolish: The user has asked several "soft questions" here before, and in those questions it became clear that their goal was to make a video game which involves correct physical simulations and the microscopic level. We recommended not to do this, but they persisted, and that's their right. So I knew this wasn't a homework question, but I completely agree that it looks like one. Now you asked "Is there a policy about HW questions?". I believe that we have the power to do things "right" here, unlike SO and Physics.SE which are just too big. I've asked the OP for more info.

Comment: @NikeDattani can you please point out some rules that I am violating here? Like a real document that is present in this site? If there are some I will take it into account for next time. If there are none, we should not be having a discussion about it.

Comment: @NikeDattani also I never said 'video game which involves correct physical simulations and the microscopic level'. Its a 'sandbox-game-like application' for first (big difference). Second the simulation will be approximation of the Real thing, so you can't call it correct.  And last I never said 'microscopic level', but I can't comment more on that as it would be just handing over all of my project idea. I am really grateful for all the help, but please don't toss around false statements that make me look like an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: Everybody knows here (including me!) that doing precise physics in a video game on atomic scale/level is impossible even with a bad ass super computer. Because of the size and count of the atoms that interact each with other. That are not my intentions and never was. It will use atom interaction as base, but that as far as I can tell for now. Explaining the whole idea in SO post is just not viable. Its more like a paper on 8 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a force $F$ acting on a mass $m$, the acceleration according to classical mechanics is:

$$\tag{1}
a = \frac{F}{m}.
$$

Given the speed $v(0)$ at time $t=0$ and the acceleration, we can obtain the speed at any time by one of the "[big four](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations)" kinematic equations which are usually taught in high school physics, and most certainly taught in every first-year university physics curriculum on the planet. The relevant kinematic equation for your question is:

$$\tag{2}
v(t) = v(0) + a\cdot t.
$$

Substituting Eq. (1) into Eq. (2) gives us:

$$\tag{3}
v(t) = v(0) + \frac{F}{m}t.
$$

If $v(0)$ is given to you in Angstroms/second, we simply need to ensure that $Ft/m$ is also in Angstroms/second. If $F$ is given to you in eV/Angstrom, $m$ is given to you in kg, and $t$ is being measured in seconds, we can start by converting the Force into SI units:

$$\tag{4}{\tiny
F ~~\textrm{[eV/Angstrom}] \times \left( \frac{1.60218\times10^{-19} \textrm{J}}{\textrm{eV}}\right) \times \left( 1 ~~\frac{\textrm{kg}\cdot {\textrm{m}}^2/\textrm{s}^2}{{\textrm{J}}}\right)\times \left(\frac{10^{10} \textrm{Angstroms}}{\textrm{m}}\right)^2 = F~~\textrm{[kg $\cdot$ Angstroms/s$^2$]}}.$$

So your force in eV/Angstrom just needs to be multiplied by 16.0218 to get a force in kg$\cdot$Angstroms/s$^2$. You can then multiply it by the time in seconds, and divide by the mass in kg, and you will get the "change in speed" in Angstroms/s from the starting speed of $v(0)$ which is also given in Angstroms/s, therefore yielding a final speed in Angstroms/s.

Note that all of this assumes that the acceleration is constant, which means the force needs to be constant.